# Sub URL's for Spring MVC @RequestMapping's

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I'm building up some RESTful WebServices via Spring MVC.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ws/contact")
@Scope("request")
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
public class ContactsController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public SearchResult search(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/id", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public SearchResult getIds(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
```

This is working great for me mapping a GET to `/ws/contact` to do a search supplied on the parameters.

But now I want to map another GET to `/ws/contact/id`, that will return just the ids.

At present the first mapping `/ws/contact` is "winning", which makes total sense. I tried adding `value="/"` to the first `@RequestMapping`, but that just stopped everything working.

Is it possible to do more specific "sub" mappings with Spring MVC?

Comment: It should simply work. The best match should win, so the behavior you describe shouldn't be the case. Post some configuration and code you tried.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/ids", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public Object getcontactIds() throws Exception {
  
 }


This should work

Comment: It's a GET, and the parameters are on the URL.

Comment: Your mapping is `/id` not `/ids`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a parameter should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public SearchResult getIds(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
```

then you can process the id in your function